# Java: cannot find symbol()

Tags: java

Ok, I'm pretty new to using Java. So. I have been reading a few books and following some online tutorials so far. I have done mostly php and javascript for about 10 years. PHP doesn't seem to be a heavy OOP language and JS with it's whole prototyping was always weird to me. I thought learning Java would be a good healty way to wrap my head around a solid OOP language.

Anyhow -
Question is accessing and printing my variable p. If I have it as a String as below, it works great. When I change it everywhere to be and Int. It breaks. Why?

```
 class Player {
        private int level;

        public Player(int level) {
            this.level = level;
        }

        public void toString(int value) {
            this.level = value;
        }
    }

    public class RPG {
        public static void main(String[] args) { 

            // Set up Keyboard input
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("What is your current level?");
            int l = keyboard.nextInt();

            Player p = new Player(l);

            System.out.println("Your level is: " + p.toString);
       }
    }
```

New Error:

```
RPG.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable toString
location: class Player
        System.out.println("You level is: " + p.toString);
                                               ^
1 error
```

If I change p to be an int everywhere. I receive the errors below: (this has been answered)

```
RPG.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Int
location: class Player
    private Int level;
            ^
RPG.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Int
location: class Player
    public Player(Int level) {
                  ^
RPG.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Int
location: class Player
    public Int GetLevel() {
           ^
3 errors
```

It is common to just pass Strings through an Object and that's it? If that's the correct wording, please correct me if I'm wrong. I want fully understand the terminology too.

Also another question. Say I wanted to take a user input and plug that into their Player level. (say I could then do the math to alter their player stats). Would I then need to make use of a getter and setter even needing in this case?

Comment: Java is case sensitive, `Int` should be `int`

Comment: Wow, ok. Dumb question then. I did not realize it was that picky. What about collecting user info? Where would be the best placement in terms of best practice, inside the class of it's own?

Comment: Collection of information is a broad question.  Based on the fact that it seems to be a console based program, I would say you would need a central point where input can be gained and then, based on the state, can be processed and delivered to the required entities/objects

Comment: I edited my post above. Using import java.util.Scanner; at the top of the program. My question is how would I pull the variable into the top class? Use a getter and setter?

Comment: You would use a `setter`, because you need to "set" the value...

Comment: The constructor is fine (as you're current doing it). Ask a new question though, this code is very different from your original question. Why change `print()` to `ShowLevel()` (note caps) instead of `toString()` like I told you? Finally, `ShowLevel()` is not `showLevel`.

Comment: Ok, I need to do more reading on this I guess. Thanks for the info to start this. Yeah I figured I need to start a new questions. Thanks a ton for the info again.

Comment: No. `System.out.println("You level is: " + p.toString);` should be `System.out.println("Your level is: " + p.toString());` or just `System.out.println("Your level is: " + p);` And look at my answer again, `toString()` returns String, it doesn't print a String.

Comment: A field is not a method. A method is not a field.

Comment: I see. Starting to understand. So would the `toString()` be considering a setter in this case? I updated my code. Working minus I'm seeing a `Your level is: Player@3ebfc8e0 value` now when I set the input to 5.

Comment: Should I just delete this whole post since it was a bad question and is on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can choose the wrapper type

```
Integer
```

or the primitive type

```
int
```

You cannot use `Int` (unless you've written one). Finally, you should probably rename `print()` into an override of `toString()`.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return level; // <-- or String.valueOf(level); // when it's an int.
}
```

And then

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  Player p = new Player("5");
  // p.print();
  System.out.println(p);
```

}

Comment: I see. How they had Int in this tutorial I have. Added to the confusion.

Comment: @tdm Are you learning Scala, or Java? Because `Int` is legal in the former not the later.

Comment: @tdm Yeah, maybe find another tutorial.

Comment: Yeah. Feel somewhat discouraged from hitting this small dumb hangups with this lang. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Int` type in Java unless you create it yourself.

You should use `int` instead.

`String` is a class rather than a primitive type like `int`, which is why it's capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have primitive types (byte, short, int, double, long, float, char, boolean), written all in lower cases and you can use also wrapper classes (Integer, Boolean, String, Long, Double, Byte, Character), which are written capitalized, and can offer some methods that primitive types cannot offer.
Your error, as somebody has already said, is that you're using `Int` instead of `int` (primitive type) or `Integer`, which is the wrapper class, which provides methods, for example, to convert a string-number ("12") to a number (12).

Hope this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class

Example with the Integer wrapper class:

```
    Integer myInt = Integer.valueOf("12");// Integer wrapper class holding
                                            // an int

    //Integer class provides a method to return the integer primitive type value
    System.out.println(myInt.intValue());

    //But you can directly output the value using 'myInt'

    System.out.println(myInt));
```